# Laravel where и orWhere не работает

Tags: mysql, laravel

Мой запрос выглядит так

```
select * from `user_profile_details` where (`user_id` = 2 and `address_type` = 'billing') or (`user_id` = 2 and `address_type` = 'residence')
```

и результат этого запроса всегда возвращает последное условие

вот сам код

```
$checkoutUserDetails = UserProfileDetail::where([
          ['user_id', $user->id],
          ['address_type', 'billing']
        ])->orWhere([
          ['user_id', $user->id],
          ['address_type', 'residence']
        ])->get();
        $checkoutUserDetails['order_data'] = $orderData;
```

Comment: не знаю это ваш лаварел, но можно переписать  where (`user_id` = 2 and `address_type` in ('billing','residence')

Comment: Знаете мне нужно так, если есть billing address, то надо взять это, иначе residence address, ваш запрос будет работать так?

Comment: это два идентичных запроса, сформулированных по-разному. А вот это - "если есть billing address, то надо взять это, иначе residence address,", стоит уточнить

Comment: Ваш запрос выберет для второго юзера записи в которых типе адреса присутствует одно из слов, моя версия сделает тоже самое

Comment: Значит только с помощью Mysql этого достичь не возможно да?

Comment: я не понимаю смысла вашей фразы :( может пример данных и результат?

Comment: В моем сайте клиент может иметь два адреса: адрес доставки и адрес проживания, и когда он делает заказ, открывается форма, где он видеть свои данные, и если у него два адреса он будет видеть адрес доставки, в противном случае тот адрес который у него есть.

Comment: я только вот так сложно могу сделать `SELECT user_id, COALESCE(b,r) FROM ((select user_id, val b, null r from s where user_id =3 and address_type='b')  union (select user_id,null b, val r from s where user_id =3 and address_type='r')) t`

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-query-using-where-with-or-and-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$checkoutUserDetails = UserProfileDetail::where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('address_type', 'billing')
              ->orWhere('address_type', 'residence');
    })
->get();
```

Данный запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select * from `user_profile_details` where `user_id` = 2 and (`address_type` = 'billing' or `address_type` = 'residence')
```

Если вам нужно прям как в вопросе, то делайте так:

```
$checkoutUserDetails = UserProfileDetail::where(function($query) use ($user){
    $query->where('user_id', $user->id)
          ->where('address_type', 'billing');
})->orWhere(function($query) use ($user){
    $query->where('user_id', $user->id)
          ->where('address_type', 'residence');
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

На mysql можно так. COALESCE возьмет первое не null значение

```
SELECT user_id, COALESCE(b,r) 
   FROM (
     (select user_id, val b, null r 
        from your_table 
        where user_id = 2 and address_type = 'billing')
     union 
     (select user_id, null b, val r 
         from your_table 
         where user_id =2 and address_type='residence')) t
```